# Can't access template page--node--1.tpl.php by its path

Tags: 7, theming

I'm trying to access template page--node--1.tpl.php through /node/1 but seeing 'The requested page "/node/1" could not be found.'

What can I do with this to access this template?

I'm using Drupal 7 and the template is in theme/templates folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting a 404 for the path "node/1" then that node doesn't exist, so the template will not be run for it. A template file will only be applied to a path that actually exists.

You just need to get the `nid` of an existing node and replace the id in the template file name with that, e.g.

```
page--node--2.tpl.php
```

where a node with a `nid` of 2 actually exists in the database.

Don't forget to clear Drupal's caches anytime you add/remove a template file so the theme registry gets updated.

Comment: how can I create and assign a given node to a given template, so that I could load that template?

Comment: Just pop to **http://mysite.com/node/add/page** and add a new node. Once you've done that you'll get a node ID (`nid`) which you can use as described in the answer above. If you need to get the `nid` you can get it from the node edit URL which will be something like **node/12/edit**, where **12** is the node ID